# Iterator over list and change values

Tags: python, list, python-2.6

I'm trying to loop over a list of variables and make changes to them if required. Can anyone help fix this problem ?. When I print the second time the list is unchanged. I am expecting `b` and `c` to be `{'lol'}` `{'test'}` respectively. I am trying to do this, without creating a new list for the values but instead modifying the original variables.

```
a = 'a,b'
b = 'lol'
c = 'Test'
d = None

print a, b, c, d

f = lambda x: '{' + x + '}' if ',' not in x else x

for i in [a, b, c, d]:
    if i:
        i = f(i)

print a, b, c, d
```

Update:

```
def do_work(self, args):
    if args.a:
        if ',' not in args.a:
            args.a = '{' + args.a + '}'

    if args.b:
        if ',' not in args.b:
            args.b = '{' + args.b + '}'

    self.do_more_work(args)
```

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using a lambda and the ternary operator to define `f`. It makes the code harder to read and gains you nothing. A simple `def f(x): ...` using an if statement and returns would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map`your lambda function, map iterates over a list and applys a function for each element generating a NEW list:

```
a = 'a,b'
b = 'lol'
c = 'Test'
d = None

print(a, b, c, d)

f = lambda x: '{' + x + '}' if x and ',' not in x else x

my_list = [a, b, c, d]
my_list = map(f, my_list)

print (my_list)
```

## Edit

In case you need the original values to be changed (as commented) you can just unpack them:

```
a, b, c, d = my_list = map(f, my_list)
print(my_list)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)

['a,b', '{lol}', '{Test}', None]
a,b
{lol}
{Test}
```

Comment: What about `f(None)`? Your code will not handle this case.

Comment: But the original values a, b, c and d are unchanged. The problem I'm facing involves named parameters, which I would like to keep within the argparse Namespace, so I don't need to take the rest out., before continuing with the rest of the program

Comment: I've cleaned up the question. Sorry for the unclear original question! This works, but the original values will still be the same when passed to the next function

Comment: @Alan, know you may not want to create a new list, but I suggest to let python do his job, just take the values unpacking the list.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't applied any change on your list.Actually in following line :

```
i = f(i)
```

`i` is just a throw away variable and doesn't point to your list items.
And by reassigning it you just changed it for a moment till next iteration.

If you want to change the list items you need to access them by indexing, you can put the list in variable and loop over your list object then change the items by indexing. For that aim you can use `enumerate` like following :

```
a = 'a,b'
b = 'lol'
c = 'Test'
d = None

print(a, b, c, d)

f = lambda x: '{' + x + '}' if ',' not in x else x

my_list = [a, b, c, d]
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    if j:
        my_list[i] = f(j)

print (my_list)
```

Or as a more pythonic way you can use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ([f(i) if i else i for i in my_list])
```

Comment: In the pythonic way there is no need to enumerate the list. The index is not necessary.

Comment: @Dunes Indeed, I just missed that. Thanks for attention.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question. Sorry for the unclear original question! This works, but the original values will still be the same when passed to the next function